# Scala's SBT and REST Java Client for JIRA

Tags: scala, sbt, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to add **REST Java Client for JIRA** to my Scala project.
I have found instruction that I should add to my **build.sbt** file here: [https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client/1.0](https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.atlassian.jira%3ajira-rest-java-client/1.0)

```
libraryDependencies += "com.atlassian.jira" % "jira-rest-java-client" % "2.0.0-m2"
```

However I am receiving an error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.atlassian.jira#jira-rest-java-client;2.0.0-m2: not found
```

I thought SBT don't know about right repository with this library and I added:

```
resolvers += "Jira repository" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/"
```

Now I receive error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6: configuration not found in commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1-atlassian-2 compile
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm new to Scala and Java infrastructure - what is the right process for adding new library to the project?

---

PS. Here is **build.sbt** file content:

```
name := "MyJiraTest"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.6" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0-M2"

libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.175"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-time_2.10.0-M7" % "0.6"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.2.2"

libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5.1"

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.5",
    "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

libraryDependencies += "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" % "slick-pg_2.10" % "0.5.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" % "slick-pg_joda-time_2.10" % "0.5.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" % "slick-pg_play-json_2.10" % "0.5.3"

resolvers += "Jira repository" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/"

libraryDependencies += "com.atlassian.jira" % "jira-rest-java-client" % "2.0.0-m2"
```

---

PPS. output from **sbt about**:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /.../MyJiraTest/project
[info] Set current project to MyJiraTest (in build file:/.../MyJiraTest/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.5
[info] The current project is {file:/.../MyJiraTest/}myjiratest 1.0
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

---

PPPS. **sbt "show externalResolvers"**:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /.../MyJiraTest/project
[info] Set current project to MyJiraTest (in build file:/.../MyJiraTest/)
[info] ArrayBuffer(FileRepository(local,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)), public: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, Sonatype OSS Snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots, Jira repository: https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 30, 2014 10:15:43 AM
```

Comment: Did you do `reload` or restarted the sbt console? Because after adding the resolver as you did, the dependency resolves for me.

Comment: I even restarted IntelliJ IDEA but still see the same error when I try to "sbt compile" or "sbt run" in it's Terminal window. And when I remove this line "libraryDependencies += "com.atlassian.jira" % "jira-rest-java-client" % "2.0.0-m2""  it works well.   What is strange is that when I hit "Run" button in the IDEA's toolbar project runs. However anyway I don't see any "com.atlassian" libs in External Libraries tree and can't import.

Comment: I would recommend not use Intellij IDEA for diagnosing problems, as the Scala plugin sometimes yields false negatives. Could you share your complete `build.sbt` and the output from `about` and `show externalResolvers` ?

Comment: Added to the post (can't put it here due to character limits)

Comment: Please either run sbt, and then in console `show externalResolvers` or run `sbt "show externalResolvers"`

Comment: I created a new project and put your build.sbt there. I'm using sbt 0.13.5 and there are no errors in update phase. Are there any other sbt related files?

Comment: @KonstantinTrunin I have also tried with your build.sbt resolvers also look ok. Can you add output of `last update` after running `update` which failed. Do you have any extra global configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the atlassian repository in my project. I think you need to change the entry you add to "resolvers" in your build.sbt

```
resolvers += "releases"  at "https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/"
```